# What is the best setup for multiple DAGs using airflow?

Tags: airflow

If I have tasks 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5,
and I want to have 1 -> 2, then 2->3, 2->4, 2->5, what is the best set up for doing this?
Would `3.set_upstream(2)`, `4.set_upstream(2)`, `5.set_upstream(2)` sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's enough. Don't forget also `2.set_upstream(1)`